# In a mesh made of cubes with different colors, how do I find the matching clusters?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, vector, three.js

### **Defining cluster**

Any group of cubes of the same color, touching face planes, not their corners.

A cluster would form a solid geometric shape.

### **To help visualize the problem**

Let's assume each one of these Legos is `1x1` units large.

[image: legos]

In a simplified code example - let's look at a `2x2x2` mesh made of `1x1x1` cubes:

```
var mesh = [ 

  // First layer   ( x, y, z )
  new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 1 )

  //Second layer   ( x, y, z )
  new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 1 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 0 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1 )
];
```

[image]

Each cube in the mesh has a color:

```
//Indexes of mesh array sorted by color
var colors = {
  red: [0, 1, 4, 6],
  green: [2, 3, 5, 7]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your `typeMap` means, what do you mean by "cubes touching faces", and what is the relevancy of the vectors here (is it not always a "3d box"?)

Comment: @Amit I tried to simplify the language a bit more - I hope this is easier to understand. Please let me know if this makes sense - It's a difficult problem to articulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved with [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). The Wikipedia page is instructive for two dimensions:

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. If target-color is equal to replacement-color, return.
 2. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 3. Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 4. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 5. Return.
```

You can extend this to three dimensions by observing that two cells are adjacent if their distance is 1, or more simply if they differ by one in exactly one dimension, so you can iterate over all six neighbors instead of the four for two dimensions.

Comment: This is a really interesting solution. So correct me if I'm wrong but, I would need to re-seed every time there are no more available target color but nodes that haven't been traversed yet right? Since a seeds color is known, I would set that as the target color for each seed traversal?

Comment: Correct, you'd need to iterate over every block and if the block has not been flooded yet, execute flood fill on that color, starting with that block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example for your mesh using my [n-dimensional-flood-fill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n-dimensional-flood-fill) npm package:

```
// It's easier to use floodFill if you represent your mesh as nested arrays:
var mesh = [
  [
    // 0,0,0  0,0,1
    ["red", "red"],

    // 0,1,0  0,1,1
    ["red", "green"],
  ],
  [
    // 1,0,0  1,0,1
    ["green", "green"],

    // 1,1,0  1,1,1
    ["red", "green"]
  ]
];

var redFill = floodFill({
  getter: function (x, y, z) { return mesh[x][y][z] },
  seed: [0, 0, 0]
});

var greenFill = floodFill({
  getter: function (x, y, z) { return mesh[x][y][z] },
  seed: [1, 1, 1]
});

console.log("redFill: " + JSON.stringify(redFill.flooded));
// redFill: [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,1]]

console.log("greenFill: " + JSON.stringify(greenFill.flooded));
// greenFill: [[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,1]]
```

You could write a different `getter` if you want to use some other representation.

As you can see, you need to run `floodFill` for each region you want to fill. To find all regions for the mesh, you could run `floodFill` from every possible starting coordinate, excluding those that have already been included in one of the flooded regions. This would be fairly efficient, but there are probably more sophisticated ways to find all regions in a single pass.